# django/python 3.5 imports/separating views.py into separate files

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I've looked at just about everything I can here. I'm using python 3.5 and i've seen stuff about how they've changed the way imports work. My django project structure is like this:

```
project
  --app
    --views/
      --__init__.py
      --myFile.py
    --__init__.py
    --models.py
    --admin.py
    --urls.py
    --etc....
```

My `urls.py` is such:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^api$', views.function_from_myFile_that_is_not_being_found),
   otherurls()...
]
```

The error I'm getting is `AttributeError: module 'app.views' has no attribute 'function_from_myFile_that_is_not_being_found'`
I'm really lost as to why this is happening. I've tried putting imports in my `__init__.py` files and that hasn't worked either. Not sure what else I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project `views` is a package, not a single module. So you should do

```
from .views import myFile as views
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to have multiple files in `views/` and I want to add them all at once like that. Is that possible?

Comment: @pianoman102 Yes, you should add for this into `__init__.py` file inside `views` package something like this: `from .myFile import *`.

Comment: Ok, Then what goes in the `urls.py` import statement?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Did I miss some simple explanation in the docs describing that kind of syntax or something??

Comment: @pianoman102 Probably you should read more about packages and modules in python. Check this article as start: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/